# Dropdown from Combobox- right click

Tags: vba

I have a ComboBox and i would like to show a msgbox, when user uses RightClick on specific item from dropdown list - without choosing this item. Is it possible?

It doesn't work how i would like. This msgbox shows only for choosen item, but i would to show this msgbox from dropdown list level, for each item, without choosing this item and without collapsing whole dropdownlist.

My code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Mousedown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Button = xlSecondaryButton Then
        Select Case ComboBox1.Value
            Case Is = "1"
                MsgBox "Description of item1"
                ComboBox1.Value = ""
            Case Is = "2"
                MsgBox "Description of item2"
                ComboBox1.Value = ""
            Case Is = "3"
                MsgBox "Description of item2"
                ComboBox1.Value = ""
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Select your combobox in the left-hand dropdown of the code-behind (worksheet? userform?) code pane, then select the `MouseDown` event in the right-hand dropdown; the VBE generates an event handler stub, put your `MsgBox` there. That said, please read [ask].

Comment: But it causes that item is choosen and Dropdown list collpses- even if i set combobox1.value="". I would to only show msgbox - without collapsing or Dropdown list.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify - right now it's collecting close votes because it's too broad and unclear. Are you handling `MouseDown` and only reacting to a right-click? Show us your code!

Comment: Thanks for editing! Question: how are the combobox items populated?

Comment: It'a list (dropdown) of all items added during event UserForm_Initialize
I was about list of all items from dropdown list and checking, which of them is selected, but i wasn't able to find this kind of property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I see what you're trying to achieve.

Unfortunately, no, a combobox doesn't work like that. You could conceivably use some very complicated Win32 message handling to hack it up, but at the end of the day ActiveX controls are only as configurable as they're designed to be, and the "dropdown" part of a combobox isn't going to fire an event for what you are trying to do.

Your users aren't going to be expecting a combobox to behave that way, either - so implementing that would introduce a UX / feature discoverability issue.

This feels very much like an X-Y problem: the *real* problem being that you want each dropdown item to have an associated description, so that the user knows what they're about to pick, before they pick it.

Turns out, a combobox can do this natively.

I don't know how you're populating your combobox, but if you can have your data (including the descriptions) in a 2D array (you can get one for free if the data comes from a worksheet `Range`), you can configure the combobox to display its items on 2 columns, and you could even hide the meaningless-to-the-user numeric code if you want:

```
Dim items
ReDim items(1 To 3, 1 To 2)
items(1, 1) = 1
items(1, 2) = "Description for Item 1"
items(2, 1) = 2
items(2, 2) = "Description for Item 2"
items(3, 1) = 3
items(3, 2) = "Description for Item 3"

ComboBox1.List = items
ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 2
'ComboBox1.ColumnWidths = "30,70"
ComboBox1.ColumnWidths = "0,70"
```

With `ColumnWidths = "0,70"` you get this:

[image: userform combobox showing only descriptions]

And with `ColumnWidths = "30,70"` you get this:

[image: userform combobox showing codes and descriptions]

The `.Value` of the combobox will be whatever the first column contains, even if it's hidden:

[image: label showing selected value in the combobox]

Comment: This description is very long that's why i wanted to include (in combobox) only a short name of all items and add some kind of legedn to all items from dropdown, because this short names can be unclear for users.
Now it's clear - thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Nakahed You can control the `ListWidth` if you need it wider than the combobox itself.

Comment: I know about it, but it doesn't look fine, that's why i wanted to pop-up msgbox with description - i thought it's a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you have access to Visual Studio you could make an `ItemTemplate` for combobox items in WPF (say, with word-wrapped descriptions and an icon), wrap up your WPF UI with a WinForms dialog, compile the thing into a COM-visible DLL, and invoke it from VBA.